# Import Data from Excel to Access from a Specific Tab

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run an Access function that imports data from a specific tab in an Excel workbook. So far, I have only found a way to get it from the workbook but I'm no sure where to specify the tab.

The code is as follows where tbl is the Access table in a string, and url is the Excel workbook path.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM " & tbl & ";")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, tbl, url, True, ""
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the *Range* argument of [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access) which you leave blank and add an exclamation point to specify entire used range of worksheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, tbl, url, True, "mySheetName!"

' WITH VARIABLE
sht = "mySheetName"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, tbl, url, True, sht & "!"
```

Alternatively, use an SQL query in the below format which uses `$` instead of `!` for sheets:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Table]
SELECT *
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx].[SHEET1$];
```

And then call it in Access VBA with `CurrentDb.Execute` which avoids resetting warnings:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM " & tbl & ";", dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [" & tbl & "] " & _
                  "SELECT * " & _
                  "FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & url & "].[" & sht & "$];", dbFailOnError
```